# TwoWay binding doesn't update controls

Tags: wpf, data-binding

The simplest example I could think of was the following:

```
TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();

this.Content = new StackPanel() { Children = { tb1, tb2 } };

Binding binding = new Binding("Text") {
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
    Source = tb1,
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
};

tb2.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
```

When I start my application I expect the textboxes to update their text as soon as the other textbox's text changes. But neither the source textbox nor the target textbox updates its text when changing the other textbox. **Is there a reason for this strange behavior and might there be a workaround?**

(For specific reasons I cannot use XAML, where bindings always worked for me)

---

**Update:** When changing the text of one of the textboxes for the first time, the output window says *The thread 0x#### has exited with code 259 (0x103).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong `DependencyProperty`.

```
tb2.SetBinding(**TextBlock**.TextProperty, binding);
```

Copied code works as expected when using `TextBox.TextProperty`

Comment: Ok. That's embarassing... Thank you :)

Comment: We all do it between those two, I'm sure of it.